# is there a function same as rtrim() and ltrim() of php in cakephp?

Tags: string, cakephp, trim

Well, here's what I have to do. I need to trim the whitespaces in the trailing and leading of strings in cakephp strings. I though it would be easy since in php, it is as simple as using the rtrim() and ltrim() functions in php. When I searched in google, I found myself lost in searching for almost an hour. Is there really any function of trimming whitespaces in cakephp? What could be it if there's any? Any tutorial or codes?  :(  thank you in advance guys.

Comment: well, you could use ltrim, rtrim and trim itself in cakePHP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there a function same as rtrim() and ltrim() of php in cakephp?

CakePHP is made in PHP and uses PHP so you can go ahead and still use `ltrim`, `trim` and `rtrim` functions in CakePHP.

Answer (score 0):

if native `rtrim()` can satisfy your needs. why should Cake have a function that do the same thing.

basic programming for any language.

> DRY principle - Don't Repeat Yourself.
>
> Single responsibility principle - each function should do only one
>   thing.

so if you need some string cleaning functionality, see [Data Sanitization class](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1184/paranoid)